Is there a way to share an instanced variable between all blueprints in Flask?
I'm making a project that involves using Flask and Pocketbase db for a website. Problem is everytime I switch to a page on a different blueprint, I have to reconnect and login to the Pocketbase server again using stored sessions. Here's my example:
Main.py
from flask import * #MAKE SURE TO INSTALL FLASK BEFOREHAND
#from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor
from pocketbase import PocketBase #MAKE SURE TO INSTALL Pocketbase BEFOREHAND
from pocketbase.client import FileUpload
from user.user import user
from classroom.classroom import classroom

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(user, url_prefix="/user")
app.register_blueprint(classroom, url_prefix="/classroom")

client = PocketBase('https://####-#####.pockethost.io')

user.py
from flask import *
from pocketbase import PocketBase #MAKE SURE TO INSTALL Pocketbase BEFOREHAND
from pocketbase.client import FileUpload

user = Blueprint("user", __name__, static_folder="", template_folder="templates")
client = PocketBase('https://####-#####.pockethost.io')

@user.route("/")
def home():
    if "login" in session:
        if client.auth_store.base_model == None:
            client.collection("users").auth_with_password(session["login"][0], session["login"][1])

classroom.py
from flask import *
from pocketbase import PocketBase #MAKE SURE TO INSTALL Pocketbase BEFOREHAND
from pocketbase.client import FileUpload

classroom = Blueprint("classroom", __name__, static_folder="", template_folder="templates")
client = PocketBase('https://####-#####.pockethost.io')

@classroom.route("/")
def home():
    if "login" in session:
        if client.auth_store.base_model == None:
            client.collection("users").auth_with_password(session["login"][0], session["login"][1])

Is there a way so that I can just use one instance of Pocketbase for all blueprints?
I tried passing the Pocketbase instance through the sessions but it doesn't work.

it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
wildcard imports pollute the namespace.

Why are you fetching db credentials from the session? That means exposing the credentials to the user which is downright wrong. Db creds belong to the .env file.

Create a different .py file called extensions.py in the same directory as your Main.py (and also a config.py to store your credentials)
extensions.py
from config import DefaultConfig
from pocketbase import PocketBase


client = PocketBase(DefaultConfig.POCKETBASE_CREDENTIALS)

config.py
class DefaultConfig(object):

    POCKETBASE_CREDENTIALS = "https://####-#####.pockethost.io"

Now you can import the client instance from extensions.py in user.py or classroom.py like:
from ..extensions import client

And obviously, you don't have to initialize a client instance in Main.py either.

You can also use JWT in Flask to generate a token with PocketBase. When the user enters their username and password, a JWT token is created, which can then be used to access all the routes you want.
